# SQL sort a table and update it from top to bottom

Tags: sql

I have a list that looks kinda like this:

```
id      Name        parentID     position
10      Object10    null         1
20      Object20    10           20
30      Object30    10           85
40      Object40    10           48
50      Object40    20           123
```

Now I want to grab all rows with the parentId `10` and sort them

`select * from table1 where parentId=10 ORDER BY id ASC`

The List should now look something like this:

```
id      Name        parentID     position
20      Object20    10           20
30      Object30    10           85
40      Object40    10           48
```

What I want to do now is change the values in the column `position`. I want to change the numbers so they start from 0 and count up till they arrived at the last element in this sorted list. This should look like this:

```
id      Name        parentID     position
20      Object20    10           0
30      Object30    10           1
40      Object40    10           2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server:
For only one parent id:

```
select ID, Name, ParentID, 
       RowNumber() Over (Order By ID) Position from table1 
   where parentId=10 
   ORDER BY id ASC
```

For all records partitioned by parentID:

```
select ID, Name, ParentID, 
       RowNumber() Over (Partition By ParentID Order By ID) Position from table1  
   ORDER BY ParentID, id
```

Looks like this will work for the following:

> CUBRID - DB2 - Firebird - Informix - Oracle - PostgreSQL - SQL Server - Sybase SQL
>   Anywhere - Teradata

https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/